# How to handle Multiple PUT and PATCH request at the same time

Tags: rest, http, patch, put

I've been asked this question somewhere .

There is a resource , lets say a Person .
we want to update salary of the person , 
suppose initial salary is 10000

```
PUT - salary = 20000
PUT - salary = 30000
PATCH - Salary = 15000 
PATCH - Salary = 0
PUT - salary = 40000
PATCH - salary = 25000
PATCH - salary = 23000
PUT - Salary = 50000
```

These above all REST calls  are executed in  parallel..all put and patch requests are executing in parallel.

can idempotentcy can play a part in here.

How will I ensure that salary should be 50000 at last

and , how to handle multiple rest calls

Answer (score 0):

Both PUT and PATCH have remote authoring semantics - "make your copy of this resource look the same as my copy".  What you have described here is analogous to hitting "Save" eight times.  If those saves happen concurrently, with no controls, then you are probably going to end up in a "last writer wins" situation, which could mean:

```
PUT - salary = 20000
PUT - salary = 30000
PATCH - Salary = 15000 
PUT - salary = 40000
PATCH - salary = 25000
PATCH - salary = 23000
PUT - Salary = 50000
PATCH - Salary = 0
```

which presumably gives you a salary of 0.

[Idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) doesn't help; you would have the same "last writer wins" effect if all of the requests had PUT semantics.

One mechanism for handling concurrent edits of a resource is to use conditional requests, see [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232).  In summary, requests use precondition headers and validators to be more specific about what sort of change is being requested "please apply these edits if your copy is still version #N"

In that scenario, a race of eight requests that share the same precondition header will result in (at most) one request being applied successfully, the others see [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2).  In effect, you replace "last writer wins" with "first writer wins".

That said... HTTP describes the *semantics* of the requests and responses; not the *implementation*.  Having understood the message, the server can do whatever it likes, and send back the appropriate response (for example, sending back a representation of what the resource looks like now, with appropriate header metadata).

What does the implementation of concurrent requests look like?  When you are applying edits to one thing, it usually involves a lock, which could be implicit or explicit.  Think transactions in a database.  Depending on what you are doing, it might be appropriate to manage the locking in the durable store, in the domain model, or both.